# Weird issues when reloading data (iOS)

Tags: ios, collectionview

I have a collectionView, called `parentCollectionView`, which scrolls horizontally.  Inside each reusable cell is a collectionView, called `childCollectionView` which scrolls vertical.

I am having a strange issue.  When I `reloadData()` on the parentCollectionView, the cell will glitch/flicker for a fraction of a second, and if you are scrolled down, it will load the childCollectionView from the top.  The weirdest thing, is that it only happens the first time you call `reloadData()` on the parentCollectionView.

Every time after that, there is no flickering, and doesn't force you to the top.  And when I ditch the `reloadData()` method and use reloadSections/IndexPaths it will for load from the top every time.

What is going on?

Comment: When are you calling `reloadData()` on the `childCollectionView`?

Comment: in the `cellForRowAtItem` method of the parentView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't call `reloadData` on the `parentCollectionView`.  Instead, I called `reloadData` on the `childCollectionViews` that are visible and set the delegate/datasource to nil, to cells that have been deallocated (in `prepareForReuse`).

It seems as reloading the `parentCollectionView` via `reloadData()` is redrawing everything.

Comment: Ah yes. `reloadData()` will on the child will only reload the items in that particular `UICollectionView`. Calling `reloadData()` on the parent would load all it's children. :)